# How can I log samba events?

Tags: samba, logs

How can I log samba events?

I have samba-shared directories and I want to know what exactly someone have download from it.
Actually, I can watch `iftop` to figured out WHO have downloaded, but not WHAT.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Chapter 9 of Using Samba - Troubleshooting Samba](http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch09_01.html):

> To turn logging on and off, set the appropriate level in the [global] section of smb.conf.

and

> By default, logs are placed in samba_directory /var/smbd.log and samba_directory /var/nmbd.log, where samba_directory is the location where Samba was installed (typically, /usr/local/samba).

You can increase the logging level to show more detailed information. So just keep increasing the level until you have information that is detailed enough for your needs.